# Converting Unix Timestamp into a time code?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena

I'm writing a query using Athena Redshift SQL

I've got two different tables where I need to join two columns: `unix_timestamp` and `timestamp_code`

`unix_timestamp` is stored as `string` that looks as such: `2018-04-01T10:05:52.047Z`

`timestamp_code` is `string` thas looks as such: `1514564885`

I want `unix_timestamp` to be converted into the format that `timestamp_code currently is in.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Would you please clarify if you are querying Athena or Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

Convert to epoch:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM '2018-04-01T10:05:52.047Z'::TIMESTAMP);
-- date_part
--------------
-- 1522577152
```

Convert from epoch to timestamp:

```
SELECT '1970-01-01'::TIMESTAMP + 1522577152 * INTERVAL '1 sec';
--      ?column?
-----------------------
-- 2018-04-01 10:05:52
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXTRACT_function.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Dateparts_for_datetime_functions.html